# AcitveRecord where method that matches just one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`Program.where(name: "xxyyzz123")` will return a collection, even if there's just one record that matches which forces me to do ugly things like:

```
puts Program.where(name: "xxyyzz123").first.age
```

or

```
puts Program.where(name: "xxyyzz123")[0].age
```

When I know for sure only one record will match, is there a shorter way to grab a property from that one record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord's dynamic attribute-based finders (find_by_x) allow you to select the first record that matches in your database. For example:

```
Program.find_by_name('xxyyzz123')
```

will return the first record with name = 'xxyyzz123'

Note that these finders are 'mildly deprecated' in Rails 4. Using

```
Program.find_by(name: 'xxyyzz123")
```

achieves the same thing and may make it easier when needing to update to the next version of Rails if they ever remove the former's functionality.

See ActiveRecord::Base in [the API](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to access that with `Program.where(name: "xxyyzz123").first.age`, however, in Rails 3, it is usually recommended to do that type of query with: `Program.find_by_name('xxyyzz123').age`.

Rails 4 deprecates the above syntax and recommends you to use the following syntax for that:
`Program.find_by(name: 'xxyyzz123')`
If you have multiple conditions, then simply : `Program.find_by(name: 'xxyyzz123', lang: 'ruby')`
Behind the scene, it does the same tomfoolery - `where` clause and returns first object.